# Is the solution set $S$ to the equations $x^3 + y^3 +z^3 = 1$ and $xy = z$ in $\mathbb{R}$ a smooth manifold?

Tags: analysis, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm working on a problem where  I need to determine whether the solution set $S$ to the equations $x^3 + y^3 +z^3 = 1$ and $xy = z$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth manifold.

I've defined $F: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ as $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x^3+y^3+z^3,xy-z)$ and now the regular level set theorem implies that $S=F^{-1}(1,0)$ is a smooth submanifold if $(1,0)$ is a regular value.

Now $(1,0)$ is a regular value if $DF_{(x,y,z)}:T_{(x,y,z)}\mathbb{R}^3 \to T_{(1,0)}\mathbb{R}^2$ is surjective for all $(x,y,z) \in F^{-1}(1,0)$.

Computing the Jacobian I got that $$DF_{(x,y,z)} = \begin{pmatrix}3x^2&3y^2&3z^2\\ y&x&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$ However now linear algebra seems to get the best of me. I don't know how to compute the rank of this matrix. I've seen some argument based on the minors, but how does that even work for a non-square matrix?

Comment: Hint: substitute the second equation into the first one, giving $x^3+y^3+x^3y^3=1 \iff (1+x^3)(1+y^3)=2$ which is the equation of the projection on the $xy$ plane of the solution curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly: $(1,0)$ fails to be a regular value if and only if all three $2\times 2$ minors are $0$. Note also that $x$ and $y$ appear symmetrically in this problem. So can we have
\begin{align*}
x^3-y^3 &= 0 \\
x^2+yz^2 &= 0 \\
y^2+xz^2 &= 0 \ ? 
\end{align*}
As we expect, we get $x=y$, and so $x(x+z^2)=0$. So, either $x=y=0$ or $x=y=-z^2$. Now put these into your defining equations. What do you find?